# How RxJS Subscriptions work when making an HTTP request?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs

```
  export class VendorHttpService {
  result = '0';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private global: GlobalService) { }

  getProfileStatus(uid: String): string {
    this.http.get(this.global.getUrl()+"/vendor/profile-status/"+uid).subscribe(
      (val: number) => {
        this.result = String(val);
        console.log("got executed "+this.result)
      }, error => {
        //console.log("error")
        this.result = error;
      }
    );
    return this.result;
  }
}
```

So, from the above piece of code in Angular 8 as you can see I am making an HTTP request to the server using **RxJS** but inside the method, I want to return the value from the request and not the whole *RxJS Subscription* to the component. As you can see I have declared a variable named **result** and I am updating it inside the method and then returning it but when I call this method *getProfileStatus()* in the component I get the initial value of 0.

I don't understand why it's not updating? I wanna know how RxJS is behaving inside the *Subscribe()* method.

Is the method *getProfileStatus()* returning before the *Subscribe()* finishes its task?

Rest assured, I have checked everything from the server & db side everything is fine there.

Comment: In addition to the answer by @asher-Kleiman below, if you want your asynchronous http requests to behave like synchronous operations, you can use a route resolver. That can automatically subscribe and return the *data* instead of an Observable stream.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, getProfileStatus() IS returning before the Subscribe() finishes its task.
When you subscribe, you are triggering the request and letting the browser know that WHEN the answer arrives, it has to handle it with the function you provided. Then it just continues with the next lines, but the function inside the subscribe is waiting to be executed.
The way I recommend to do this is to return the subscribable instead of the value and subscribe from your component. So this is would be in your service:

```
  getProfileStatus(uid: String): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get(this.global.getUrl()+"/vendor/profile-status/"+uid)
  }
```

An in your component there should be something like this:

```
constructor(private vendorHttp: VendorHttpService){}

functionName() {
  this.vendorHttp.getProfileStatus("some_uid").subscribe(
      (val: number) => {
        this.result = String(val);
        console.log("got executed "+this.result)
      }, error => {
        //console.log("error")
        this.result = error;
      }
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was voted down? This is the basic way to handle http and RxJS Observables. The function passed into the subscribe is basically a callback function that is "called back" once the data is retrieved. But by then, your function has already returned your default value.